# Can't display markdown on NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown, tailwind-css, react-markdown

Haloo, hope you have a great day!

I'm in the middle of learning something about markdown on react, i already success using react markdown editor, but now, when i want to display it, i got stuck, i'm using `react-markdown` and `NEXTJS`, and here's the problem:

importing the `library`:

```
const ReactMarkdown = dynamic(
  () => import("react-markdown").then((mod) => mod.default),
  { ssr: false }
);
const rehypeRaw = dynamic(
  () => import("rehype-raw").then((mod) => mod.default),
  { ssr: false }
);
const remarkGfm = dynamic(
  () => import("remark-gfm").then((mod) => mod.default),
  { ssr: false }
);
```

i have markdown look like this:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("# A demo of `react-markdown`");
```

and this is my div

```
<div className="container mx-auto px-0 lg:px-40 pt-6 pb-8 sm:pt-14 sm:pb-16 md:pt-14 md:pb-16 min-h-screen">
        <ReactMarkdown
          children={value}
          remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}
        />
</div>
```

and when i refresh my page, i got this:

[image: please see..]

that's not `H1`, and the `code tag` seems didn't work, **BUT** when i'm using bold:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("# A **demo** of `react-markdown`");
```

the bold is being display..

[image: please see again..]

and at this point, idk why this happend, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using TailwindCSS, the default styles for elements are reset, that's why the `h1` text will look like any other text.

You can use [`@tailwindcss/typography`](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography) to counter this.

Just add the plugin to your `tailwindcss.config.js` file

```
// tailwindcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography'), (...)],
  ...
}
```

And use the `prose` classes on the HTML elements

```
<div className="prose ...">(...)</div>
```

Also, using `Next.js` dynamic imports, you don't have to use the `then` syntax to get the default module.

```
const ReactMarkdown = dynamic(() => import("react-markdown"), { ssr: false });
```

This snippet should give you the same as importing the `default` module. Only use the `then` when you want to import a particular export

Comment: Dudeeee, you were right!!! it is because of tailwindcss, i need to export tailwind/typography to make it h1, butt, i need ask another thing, i'm already importing all the css, include the table css, but, why my table didn't appear? even tho i just using the default table still didn't appear, i think this is not because of the css anymore, because all the css (h1, a, blockquotes, etc) is perfectly appear, i think this is because of `another library` that `react-markdown` needs, am i right? just imported `remarkGfm` still didn't work..

Comment: Okeee nevermind, solved! just change `remarkGfm` from dynamic import to legacy import

Comment: TypeScript is not happy with this dynamic import